# Generally speaking, should I check if an element is in a set before inserting it?

Tags: java, set

I'm currently using Java so I'm more interested in knowing if it'd be better to just insert it, in terms of efficiency. Though I'm also curious if it's a bad practice.

Comment: It makes no semantic difference, and there's no reason it should give any performance benefit, and it's two redundant lines of code. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

No need. The API tells you if it's already there (if you need to know), and the Collections code is very efficient - more efficient than taking the trouble to check it yourself.

FYI, here's the API in action:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
boolean newAdditionToSet = set.add(1); 
System.out.println(newAdditionToSet); // true
newAdditionToSet = set.add(1); 
System.out.println(newAdditionToSet); // false
```

It's "bad practice", because the Set will *also* be checking it anyway. You're just doubling to workload for new elements, while keeping the workload for existing elements.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it is more efficient to just insert the element.  For a normal `Set` implementation, the insertion code pretty much duplicates the work of the `contains` call, because it needs to replace the value if it already exists.  So calling `contains` first is *generally* a waste of time, and is *generally* bad practice.

But not always!

One case where you should call `contains` is if you **don't want** the `add` call to replace an existing value in the set.  This situation does arise occasionally; e.g. if you are using the set to canonicalize a bunch of values.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary. Set.add() will check for you.

It will also return true or false based on whether the element was added or not.